# What is this strange flower which I found on an upheaval in Rhodes (Greece) in July?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

It looks like it carries berries instead of blossoms. Is it actually a flower or rather a baby tree? I found it in a Google image search (see here: https://goo.gl/images/vfBDSP), but there was no description with the picture.

[image: flower_rhodes_greece]

Comment: Looks like the berries of an arum.  Search for "arum berry image" and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I agree, it looks like Arum creticum from the picture.  It is a kind of lily, and these fruits form after the plant has finished flowering.